# how to fix 404 error to concern Action class ( controller) and struts.xml in struts 2 framework

Tags: java, struts2

I need your help.
I have a problem with the struts.xml and file Action class.
Fews day ago,My project is well but today when I run my project that on web browser occur 404 error as follows:

**HTTP Status 404 - /Food/Home.jsp
type Status report
message /Food/Home.jsp
description The requested resource (/Food/Home.jsp) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.16**

In Eclipse' console :
  **

```
> Unable to load configuration. - action -
> file:/E:/Java/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Food/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:7:75
>   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:431)
>   at
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3709)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4356)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413) Caused
> by: Unable to load configuration. - action -
> file:/E:/Java/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Food/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:7:75
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
>   at
> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
>   ... 19 more Caused by: Action class [controller_user.Login] not found
> - action - file:/E:/Java/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Food/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:7:75
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:409)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:354)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:468)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:264)
>   at
> org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:193)
>   at
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
>   ... 21 more

**
You should look at the error "**Caused by: Action class [controller_user.Login] not found - action - file:/E:/Java/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Food/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:7:75**".This is cause for Can not load my Home page or any else page
```

If i clear these line in the struts.xml

```
         <action name="login" class="controller_user.Login" method="loginAction">
        <result name="success">/User/Registration.jsp</result>
        <result name="failed">/User/LoginFailed.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

=> Running my project is Ok

I don't know how t fix this problem.Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your fully qualified class name in class attribute. Is controller_user your full, non-standard package name ? It should be something like:

```
<action name = "login" 
       class = "com.foo.bar.controller.user.Login" 
      method = "loginAction" >
```